# help with struts2 form & combobox

Tags: jsp, forms, combobox, struts2, action

i have a combobox in a form and when i click submit i get this error.

HTTP ERROR: 404  No result defined for action MyAction  and result input

in the action i tried to return INPUT instead of SUCCESS but still doesnt work.

any ideas what can be wrong?

thanks.

Comment: Can you give us some more to go on. Can you post the relevant sections of your struts.xml and also the code that is returning your result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have one or more validation rules failing. This causes an implicit result of "input" to be invoked

Comment: thanks. it was passing a String to the action and i thought that it would pass the object country. how can i retrieve the id of the object from the combobox?

this is what i have:

<s:combobox label="Country" name="country" headerValue="Select" headerKey="1" list="%{countries}" listValue="name"/>

Answer (score 0):

Without more information available I would be checking your struts.xml and ensuring that your action definition has an input result and that it is directing the user back to the edit page where they can correct any action or field errors.